# Performance of Selializer PHP Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony4, serialization

I am using serializer with these classes

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

public function makeSerializer(){
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $norm = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $norm->setCircularReferenceLimit(1);
    $normalizers = array($norm);

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    return $serializer;

}

public function execSerialize(Request $request){ 
    $toJson = ['key' => 'value',,,,] //about 300 line hashes;
    $serializer = $this->makeSerializer(); 
    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($toJson, 'json');
```

My $toJson variables has about 300 * 20 datas ,not that much,
but `$serializer->serialize($toJson, 'json');` costs nearly 10 seconds.

It might be too slow for web application.

Is this correct performance for Serializer??

Or I should check somewhere else or any method???

Comment: Can you not just use `json_encode()` directly?

Comment: It is quite faster. Datetime class object parsed differently though, other than that , everything works well.